# Microsoft Access: "Expression entered has a function containing the wrong number of arguments" Error

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I am recieving a error for the following when running a AutoExec function in access:
[image]

I have checked the code i wrote to run off the macro, and everything appears to be good.

[image]

```
Public Function AutoEmail(MySQL As String)
    'On Error GoTo Exit Function:
    Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim oEmailItem As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(MySQL)
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF
            If IsNull(rs!Email) Then
                rs.MoveNext
            Else
                'Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
                If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
                    Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
                End If
                    Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                With oEmailItem
        
                    .To = rs!Email
                    .Subject = "3D Due in 1 day " & rs!FullName
                    .HTMLBody = "<table><tr><td>CA Number #:</td><td>" & Trim(rs("CANum")) & "</td></tr>" & _
                        "<tr><td>Division:</td><td>" & rs("Division") & "</td></tr>" & _
                        "<tr><td>Employee Name:</td><td>" & rs("FullName") & "</td></tr>" & _
                        "<tr><td>3D Due Date:</td><td>" & Format(rs("3D Due Date"), "mmmm dd\,yyyy") & "</td></tr></table><br/><br/>" & _
                        "This email is auto generated from the Corporate Database. Please Do Not Reply!"
                    '.Body = "CA Record #:" &  Trim(rs("CA_Record_#")) & vbCr & _
                    '    "Institution:" &  rs("Institution") & vbCr & _
                    '    "Collaboration Owner:" & rs("Collaboration_Owner") & vbCr & _
                    '    "PA Expiration Date:" & Format(rs("PA_Expiration_Date"), "mmmm dd\,yyyy") & vbCr & vbCr & _
                    '    "This email is auto generated from the PMCD Collaboration Projects Database. Please Do Not Reply!"
                    .Display
                    .Send
                     rs.Edit
                     rs!dateemailsent = Date
                     rs.Update
                End With
                Set oEmailItem = Nothing
                rs.MoveNext
            End If
            'i forgot to comment this out
            'while testing the <table> format
            '
            'Exit Do
        Loop
        Set oOutlook = Nothing
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
    Else
        ' do nothing
  
    End If
    
End Function
```

I am probably missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you supplying the value for the parameter `MySQL` ?

Comment: Your function has a parameter, the macro doesn't supply it. Hence the error.

Comment: Instead of AutoExec. could have procedure called by form set to open by default when db opens.